# Termination of a thread not possible

Tags: android, multithreading

I've got an activity with the following code:

```
Handler dataLoaderHandler = new Handler();
int mInterval = 3000;
public MyActivity myself;
Thread dataLoader = new Thread( new Runnable() {
    @Override 
    public void run() {
        Log.e("MyActivity","ReloadData");
        new DataLoader(new JSONData(myself)).execute(Configuration.dataURL);
        dataLoaderHandler.postDelayed(dataLoader, mInterval);
    }
});

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myself = this;
    ... some other stuff...
    dataLoader.start();
}


... other code ...

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.e("MyActivity","onDestroy ending thread");
    try { dataLoader.join(); } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    Log.e("MyActivity","onDestroy called");
}
```

When I hit the back button my activity gets destroyed but the thread still continues to run every 3 seconds. Why is the thread not stopped or better said deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you haven't stopped it. Since calling `stop()` on a thread is already deprecated, you should stop the thread within the thread itself. This can be easily done by calling `return` on it.

However, don't expect your `Thread` to finish immediately you hit your back button. The `Thread` will probably run up until Android OS determines it has to (basically, it may take a while to stop even you call it).

You may want to check [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122324/cleanly-exit-android-app) I made a time ago, it's well answered.

Comment: Actually, I already found these solutions but it confuses me. If I call returen immediately how do I know for sure that the thread is actually stopped and not endlessly calling return?

Comment: Just put a `Log.d` instance inside. Once you terminate it, you'll see in your LogCat if it's still running or not (wait a time after stopping it so you may know for sure it's not being cached).

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
boolean finished=false;
Handler dataLoaderHandler = new Handler();
int mInterval = 3000;
public MyActivity myself;
Thread dataLoader = new Thread( new Runnable() {
    @Override 
    public void run() {
        if(!finished){
        Log.e("MyActivity","ReloadData");
        new DataLoader(new JSONData(myself)).execute(Configuration.dataURL);
        dataLoaderHandler.postDelayed(dataLoader, mInterval);}
    }
});


@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
            finished=true;
    }
```